# Extracting from a string before a specific pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to cut german wikipedia articles, to output only biographical text data (cutting away all literature, book-lists and so on). So an example of an Text could look like this:

> some relevant text == Title1 == more relevant text ===Title2=== and
>   more relevant text == some literature on person == unwanted text
>   ==books by the author== more unwanted text...

The issue is to output the text before a pattern of ==[text including the word literature or books]==. Here it would be:

> some relevant text == Title1 == more relevant text ===Title2=== and
>   more relevant text

I am using Python 3 and I tried some Regex like this (and many more):

```
seperator = re.compile(r'={2,3}\s?.*literature.*\s?={2,3}')
m = seperator.search(text)
print (text[:m.start()])
```

But, unfortunately this would only output the text until the first pattern == Title1 ==:

> some relevant text

How can I make it sensitive as to capture the first pattern that has 'literature' or 'book' within itself?

I hope I could describe the problem precisely. Thank you in advance for your help and sorry if this question was asked before, I couldn't find some solution anywhere.

BTW, its no option to distinguish between Title1 and Title2 that they come in too different sometimes and unclear so I tried to distinguish between titles that clearly mark the end of the biographical texts like literature or book for example.

Comment: Is the word `'literature'` guaranteed to be present?

Comment: It might be more helpful if you post an example of the real content you are trying to match against. Maybe even post a link to one of these articles. It might also help if you explain how you are getting the content to parse. For example, if the raw content you are receiving is html/xml/etc. it might be easier to use a parser for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure Python way doing. This splits the text on `'='` and check for the word in each split. If a match found, we break the loop and join all prior to it:

```
s = 'some relevant text == Title1 == more relevant text ===Title2=== and more relevant text == some literature on person == unwanted text ==books by the author== more unwanted text'

lst = []
for x in s.split('='):
    if 'literature' in x:
        break
    else:
        lst.append(x)

print('='.join(lst).strip('='))
# some relevant text == Title1 == more relevant text ===Title2=== and more relevant text
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, the following regex should work for you:

```regex
.+?(?=={2,3}[^=]*literature)
```

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/3dVQiT/1).

**Python 3 example:**

```
import re

regex = r".+?(?=={2,3}[^=]*literature)"
test_str = "some relevant text == Title1 == more relevant text ===Title2=== and more relevant text == some literature on person == unwanted text ==books by the author== more unwanted text..."

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

**Output:**

> Match 1 was found at 0-87: some relevant text == Title1 == more
>   relevant text ===Title2=== and more relevant text

[**Python demo**](https://rextester.com/XJR10759).

Comment: thanks a lot. That almost looks good. But the expression is failing when for example 'literature' is not part of the '== Title1 ==' but is part of the subsequently text, like 'here is some text == Title1 == some more text with literature.== Title2 with literature =='.

Here it would cut it immediately after '== Title1' not taking the following text into account and cutting at  '==Title2 with literature =='

the supposed output should be:
'here is some text == Title1 == some more text with literature'

Comment: If you want to cut only before the latest "literature", then make it greedy (i.e., remove the `?` from the pattern above). Here's a demo: https://regex101.com/r/3dVQiT/2

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your help again. But it still doesnt work out. My problem is not to cut it before the first or latest "literature". It is before the first appearance of for example "== literature ==". It is compelling that the regex looks for the word literature (or other words) in between equal signs.
Also later i would like to add other words to the list not only literature, also books, author ... and so on. And find the first appearance of "== literature or books or author ==" and then cut the text before. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @MikeTwain You didn't make that clear in your question but anyway, if you want to match from the _beginning of the string_ and cut before the first `==` that's followed by any of these words, you can use `^.+?(?=={2,3}[^=]*(?:literature|books|author|whatever))`. Here's a demo: https://regex101.com/r/0Jjfqt/1